# How to complete Operation Bloodhound competitive mission in zoo or safari?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I need your help. I got stuck in a Competitive mission of Operation Bloodhound(Safari, zoo) as no one has this operation bloodhound pass so they can't play and the players who have this coin are not playing so how to complete those mission?

I tried to play alone and was waiting for 40 minutes but no server found then I created a lobby with my 4 friend (who all have the bloodhound coin) but still after waiting for more than 20 min we couldn't find a server and they left so how can I complete those missions as i can't access other levels.

Is there any way to skip these levels?

Comment: You don't need the Operation Bloodhound pass to play the new maps.

Comment: @Lyrical, i don't think so but still players are not playing compe so is there any way to skip them?

Comment: The pass grants you access to the two sets of missions, the upgradeable coin, and access to the new skin collections. Anyone can play the maps. Regarding not being able to find a game in competitive, have you reduced the maximum ping you are willing to play with? Are you playing at times when others from your region might not be playing as much? Have you been able to play the more popular maps in competitive?

Comment: And no, you can't skip the missions, but you might be able to reach the next missions via a different route, albeit a longer way round.

Comment: yes i am playing in other compe matches and all are full but at that same time, no player in zoo or safari. .:( yes i have low ping and main issue is no route as both route got stuck at 2 compe(one is zoo, second is safari :( )

Comment: @Leothelion There is no map called safari.  Are you talking about de_season?

Comment: why negative marks on asking question which is clear? really people your standard..great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no tricks or ways to bypass the mission.

You simply have to wait in the queue until you find a game.

Changing the 'Max allowed ping setting' in options may help you find a game faster. Queuing with friends might also help.

Comment: Colin thanx for saying no but m not waiting for this answer..:( sorry

Comment: @Leothelion There's no other option. If you're looking for some exploit to bypass the missions, you can't, there's simply no way.